# Error while executing SQL query in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, h2, playframework-2.3, anorm

I'h getting problems with executing SQL query in Play 2.3 application and h2-memory db.

code where is a problem:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
Sql("").executeInsert()
}
```

Error(in InteliJ Sql is red marked)

```
anorm.Sql.type does not take parameters
```

Any ideas?

Whole class:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm._

case class User(username: String, password: String) {

def save() = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("").executeInsert()
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `SQL`, not `Sql` .. also why do you have two connections in a row?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm

Comment: If I change to SQL error is: Compilation error[not found: value SQL]

Comment: Did you `import anorm._` ? Post more code..

Comment: As already said, `SQL` should be used as query constructor, not `Sql`.

Comment: @applicius (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6343430)): Please don't *remove* version-less tags and *replace* them with the version-specific alternatives.  Doing so can reduce the visibility of a question.  Adding version-specific tags but keeping the old versionless tag is the preferred method.